# Pragmatic Programmer: Knowledge Management

Tags: knowledge-management

I am unsure what to tag this under, but I'd imagine it's a question that's relevant to most developers.

Throughout my working day, I often come across snippets of information and knowledge that will come in useful again. These may be general coding examples, or else environment specific commands etc.

Typcially, I just store these in different text files, and then refer to these text files when I am in need.
However, this is awkward and difficult to search

One alternative I've considered is creating my own local Wiki and tagging such snippets under common tags, that I can easily search.

I'd be interested to know though how other developers manage such knowledge in a "pragmatic" way.

Comment: I use my bookmarks in chrome which are nicely backed up to the cloud and decent to search.  I use the folder tree to organize them.  The problem is, link rot can happen.  I'm favoriting this question in case someone comes up with an "answer".

Comment: I think this is a http://programmers.stackexchange.com question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had a look through and TiddlyWiki seems like what I was looking for: http://www.tiddlywiki.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above, TiddlyWiki seems like the best option here

Answer (score 0):

I keep my notes in a combination of Evernote and Microsoft OneNote.

Evernote takes care of most of my note-taking while reading on the web. If you set up your notebooks in an organized way, and are diligent about tagging your notes when you create them, the built-in search makes that  information available anytime, anywhere. Advantages:

- Can group, sort and tag in as many ways as I want
- Available on all my devices
- Clipping articles and snippets is a breeze on Chrome with the
  add-on
- Simple interface

OneNote is brilliant when I'm working on my PC; it is more feature-packed than Evernote and the ability to free-form text and to paste in any other document is awesome. Wish it had the range of availability of Evernote; I wouldn't need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I was using [TreePad](http://www.treepad.com/) for that 6 or 7 years ago and it was great. The only problem was my computer crashed and I hadn't been backing up as I should have. So now I use Google Docs. The data isn't organized in the nice way that TreePad does, but I don't have to worry about backups and it has a search capability (although I have noticed a few glitches in the search before where it didn't find something I knew was there).

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good knowledge management system at that is practising typing in the right keywords in google (or bing if you prefer).

I do it many times a day and have never had the urge to save anything, or even bookmark it, as it is easy enough to find it back if required, if not through your web browser's history by typing a similar query in google.

For progamming issues you may be better of using stackoverflow.com for your searches, but stackoverflow.com results are usually on top of your search result listing anayway.